# Button not hitting if statement in Knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following button

```
    <div class="pull-right" data-bind="tooltip: { title: DashboardEdit, placement: 'top' }">
    <button class="btn actionButtonIcon" id="DashboardEdit" data-bind="click: changeButtonText">
        <figure>
            <img src="../../../Images/NotesPink.png" />
            <figcaption data-bind="text: $data.ProcurementbuttonText() ? 'Save': 'Edit'"></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </button>
</div>
```

It changes text when clicked, now what i am trying to achieve is when the button text is showing Save then it should execute a function, so i tried this:

```
            self.ProcurementbuttonText = ko.observable(false);

        self.changeButtonText = function(){
            self.ProcurementbuttonText(!self.ProcurementbuttonText())
            if (self.ProcurementbuttonText() === 'Save'){
            var data = {
                'ScorecardId':ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId'))(),
                'DashboardConfig':ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'))()
            };
            PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.Save(data);           
        }
    }
```

so when `ProcurementButtonText = save` then it should do all that which is in the if statement, but i see its never hitting that if statement

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with what you are expecting in `self.ProcurementbuttonText()` because you set it up with a boolean like so - `self.ProcurementbuttonText(false);` and then toggle it `self.ProcurementbuttonText(!self.ProcurementbuttonText())` in the changeButtonText function.  the next line you are checking to see if it equals 'Save' which it will never equal to.  it will only be true or false.
so this check just needs to be

```
if (self.ProcurementbuttonText()){
    var data = {
        'ScorecardId':ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('scorecardId'))(),
        'DashboardConfig':ko.observable(localStorage.getItem('ElementDataWidget'))()
    };
    PreferentialProcurementDashboardApi.Save(data);           
}
```

I would recommend that you look at how you are naming your variables and what they are used for because self.ProcurementbuttonText is misrepresenting what it actually contains.  At the moment it contains the view/edit state of this record and not the text of the procurement button.

Answer (score 0):

**self.ProcurementbuttonText(!self.ProcurementbuttonText())**

You did mistake in the above line. Here you are setting this observable var "ProcurementbuttonText" value to true or false. Which is always a boolean value. So it's value will never be equal to "Save". And inside if condition you are checking it is equal to "Save" which is always false. Which means it will never execute that part.